# How to pass in screen from one TabBarItem to another TabBarItem?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, segue

[image]

In the picture above,

in the Tabbar selected 1. tabbar item
A -> C -> D 
and than

in the Tabbar selected 3. tabbar item
in order of
E -> D -> A

App remembers the D screen on 1. tabbar item . I want the "A" screen to open.

Code below;

D ViewController :

```
   @IBAction func goToMapButton(_ sender: Any) {

        if let navController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] as? UINavigationController{
            if let mapController = navController.childViewControllers.first as? MapViewController{
                self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
                mapController.zoomToGeo(X: Double(PhotoItemArraySelected[0].photoLon!)!, Y: Double(PhotoItemArraySelected[0].photoLat!)!,TesisAdi: PhotoItemArraySelected[0].photoName)

            }
        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display screen A which belong to tab 1, and screen A looks to be MapViewController:

```
if let navController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] as? UINavigationController{
    if let mapController = navController.childViewControllers.first as? MapViewController{
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
        mapController.zoomToGeo(X: Double(PhotoItemArraySelected[0].photoLon!)!, Y: Double(PhotoItemArraySelected[0].photoLat!)!,TesisAdi: PhotoItemArraySelected[0].photoName)

        //add this line and to check if it works good or not.
        navController.popToViewController(mapController, animated: true)
    }
}
```